# Targeting Runtime for New MVC6 Project in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET beta 7, VS 2015 on Windows 7.

When I create a new MVC6 project in VS2015 targeting .NET 4.6 framework, my project references look like this:

```
DNX 4.5.1
DNX Core 5.0
```

I don't wish to create for cross platform, and would expect my references to look like this (from other [tutorial](http://proudmonkey.azurewebsites.net/asp-net-5-getting-started-with-mvc-6/)s):

```
ASP.NET 5.0
ASP.NET Core 5.0
```

From the ASP.NET 5.0 documentation:

[image]

What I'm seeing in VS 2015 (no check box option for dnx):

[image]

Should I just manually hack the project.json file?

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That documentation where you can select the platform is from a previous beta or preview version of ASP.NET 5 so not valid anyone.

Your project.json looks correct.

DNX is an execution environment that can run on various underlying .NET frameworks, including .NET framework 4.5.1,4.5.2 or the latest .NET Framework 4.6.

.NET Core 5 is not .NET Framework 5 but is a modular runtime and library implementation that includes a subset of the .NET Framework 4.X. So you can call it mini .NET 4X. It is not the latest version of .NET framework for Windows. The latest version is .NET Framework 4.6

If you leave your project.json by default as

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
 },
```

then when you publish your project you'll then be able to publish to either .NET Core or .NET Framework.

[image]

clr-win = .NET Framework windows

core-clr-win = .NET Core

if you do not wish to create cross platform you can edit your project.json to

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
 },
```

and you'll not be able to see the Target DNC Version of .NET Core as a choice when you publish your site.

If you need to use a later .net version feature or if you you wish to include and reference a class library which itself targets a later .net framework version to your project you would need to change your project.json to target the same or later .net framework version e.g. dnx452 or dnx46

e.g.

```
 "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { },
 },
```

As soon as you save the project.json file your project will automatically update itself. You can view the progress in the output window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why do some tutorials show the references as ASP.NET 5.0 and ASP.NET Core 5.0?

Comment: Edit your original question and put a link to that tutorial

Comment: Releases before ASP.NET 5 BETA 8 had major changes. Since Beta 8 there won't be according to the ASP.NET 5 roadmap so comparing tutorial info  between previous previews and betas would be a time waste.

Comment: Added link to other tutorial and marked as answer :)

Comment: .NET framework 5 for Windows doesn't exist so that original naming was incorrect hence the correction in a later beta by the .NET team. There is probably an entry about the renaming on github somewhere.