# What is wrong with my class library reference in an MVC 6 Web Api project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

Working in VS 2015 Community, I've created a `Services` class library project, targeted at .NET 4.6. Now, in my main `Api` project, all references fall under `DNX 4.5.1` and `DNX Core 5`. When I add the reference to `Services`, I get the compiler error :

> Dependency Services >= 1.0.0-* could not be
>   resolved  Api C:\Development\Surveys\src\Api\project.json

What do I have to do to make my class library compatible with the `Api` project?

Comment: Did you migrated `Services` class library project to DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5 or you tried to use previously compiled dll targeted to .NET 4.6 directly in MVC6 project **without** migration?

Comment: All project should be in the same folder. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565019/asp-net-5-error-referencing-net-library-on-another-path

Comment: Try change the reference "dnx451" to "dnx46". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242352/targeting-runtime-for-new-mvc6-project-in-vs-2015/33243397#33243397 or otherwise compile your class library as .net 4.5.1

Comment: @Oleg, how would I migrate the project? In Project Properties, I don't have any DNX as a platform to select?

Comment: @JuergenGutsch How can you point me to an unanswered question, especially where the question is about references not working when they're not in the same folder? Projects having to be in the same folder is a ridiculous solution, as VS should keep folder information when I add a project reference, or if ASP.NET 5 Beta is still buggy, I should be able to add path info to `project.json`. Anyway, they are all in the same solution folder.

Comment: I can point you to a lot more unanswered questions and yes ASP.NET 5 is still beta and contains many bugs. Anyway you didn't wrote about your solution structure. ;)
This types of errors always have only two reasons: 1. Projects not in the same folder. 2. Version number of the dependent library used in the project.json (to reference to another project use an empty string  instead of an explicit version)

Comment: @ProfK: you can **add new project to your ASP.NET 5 solution** in Solution context menu, choose "Class Library" (under "Web" group on the left side). You would have ASP.NET 5 project with both "DNX 4.5.1" and "DNX Core 5.0" under References. You can copy your old C# code, modify "DNX 4.5.1" to "DNX 4.6" in `"frameworks"` part of `project.json`, if it really required. The most important that you should try to create "DNX Core 5.0" version of the Class library to make the code really portable. After that you can reference **any** Dll created by one project in another one.

Comment: @ProfK: You can reference the **outer path** to the project library in the main solution. To do this one can modify `"projects"` section of `global.json` of the solution. You can add absolute path to the src directory of the library. After saving the changes in `global.json` you will see that the project will be added to the solution. In the same way you can debug the source code of MVC6 beta8 for example. You need just add the path to MVC6 sources and build the project. One will use the sources instead if installed dlls and you can debug all.

Answer (score 2):

1. Both of your projects have to target `DNX Core 5` if your main (`Api`) project supports it
2. You can't reference .net project that has higher version than source one. So both of your projects should target 4.6

The way you described the problem I'm not sure if `Services` is normal (let's call it *old*) Class Library or ASP.NET 5 Class Library. If it is *old* then your main project can not target core clr. Just remove this TFM from `project.json`.

Comment: **Different .NET versions on the 2 projects.  Doh!**